# Error al ejecutar el programa en c++ de matrices

Tags: c++

acudo nuevamente a la comunidad en busca de ayuda y aprender, el código no esta terminado pero al compilar y ejecutar, cuando hago la prueba me tira error, alguien me puede decir que esta mal?, en la facultad hice el mismo código y en la versión de dev c++ 5.11 me arroja ese error, y en una versión más vieja me andaba a la perfección.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>

using namespace std;

int main () {
    int a,b,fila,columna;
    int matriz [fila][columna];
    system ("color F3");
    cout << "\t\t\t PROGRAMA DE MATRIZ EJ 1 C++" << endl << endl;
    cout << "Ingrese el valor de filas que quiere que tenga la matriz: "; cin >> fila;
    cout << "Ingrese el valor de columnas que quiere que tenga la matriz: "; cin >> columna;
    cout << "Ingrese el valor de los elementos de la matriz: " << endl;

    for (a = 0 ; a < fila ; a++) {
        for (b = 0 ; b < columna ; b++) {
            cout << "Fila " << "[" << a << "]" << " " << "columna " << "[" << b << "]: ";
            cin >> matriz[a][b]; cout << endl;
        }
    }
    system ("pause");
}
```

Comment: ¿Y qué error te muestra?

Comment: No me muestra ningun error, compila, se tilda el probrama cuando le doy valores a los elementos de la matriz.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Buenas, no soy experto pero he visto un par de cosas que no me han acabado de gustar...

***- Matriz no inicializada:***
int a,b,fila,columna;
int matriz [fila][columna];

matriz no la tienes definida a nada: Es un puntero a una matriz bidimensional de tamaño o bien aleatorio o bien 0 (depende del compilador la variables no inicializadas se ponen a 0 o bien se dejan con "basura")

A priori te diria que eso no deberia haberte ejecutado nunca, desconozco si en algun compilador antiguo te pillaria basura para los valores iniciales de fila y columna y algo te haría, pero no lo veo claro.

2 soluciones:

**- Memoria dinamica:**
Definición int **matriz;
Una vez ya sabes las dimensiones de la matriz : matriz = malloc (ablablalbla deberias saber como va :))
[Ejemplo con google apps script](http://googleappscriptsweb.blogspot.com.es/2016/05/como-hacer-una-matriz-dinamica-con.html): No es el mimsmo lenguaje pero te será fácil convertirlo

**- Memoria estatica:**
int matriz[100][100] y que las dimensiones que introduzca el usuario nunca superen 100 o el valor que le pongas... el problema es que depende de que valores le pongas te quedaras sin memoria de pila, asi que depende del caso mejor la memoria dinámica. [Ejemplo de matriz estatica en C](http://lordpakus.blogspot.com.es/2013/10/ejemplos-de-cc-sencillos-matriz-de.html)

Aparte de lo que te he dicho anteriormente...

***- LLamadas obsoletas a sistema:***
system ("color F3");
Yo no usaria esta llamada, no creo que te de problemas, pero las llamadas a system para este tipo de cosas acostumbran a dar más problemas que otra cosa.

Comment: la matriz la define el usuario por eso no esta inicializada.

Comment: Ahí es donde tienes problemas. El problema no es la inicialización como tal sino que no tienes memoria reservada para esa matriz. O bien reservas de sobras ( estatíca) o bien reservas de forma dinamica, tal como lo tienes , no te funcionará.

Answer (score 2):

Parte de la respuesta ya la ha dado [Pako LordPakus](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/12926/2742); así que pasaré a ampliarla y *adivinar* tu problema, ya que no compartes que el error te muestra que estoy seguro que es muy revelador.

> en la facultad hice el mismo código y en la versión de dev c++ 5.11 me arroja ese error, y **en una versión más vieja me andaba a la perfección**.

Para empezar `main` no dispone de retorno, generalmente esto es marcado como alarma (warning) pero diferentes versiones de compilador o **diferentes compiladores pueden tratarlo como error**, añade `return 0;` al final de tu función `main`.

Utilizas Arreglos de Longitud Variable (VLA [en Inglés](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable-length_array)), los cuáles no pertenecen al C++ estándar si no que son una extensión del compilador (Lee sobre la extensión en [el compilador GCC](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Variable-Length.html)). Cada compilador tiene sus propias extensiones de manera que si en la facultad usas un compilador y en tus posteriores compilaciones usas otro, podría estar esta extensión desactivada o no existir y **te mostraría un error**.

---

Por otro lado, tu código muestra ciertas *carencias* de estilo, entendiendo estilo como recomendaciones no obligatorias pero útiles:

- **Ámbito de variables mayor de lo necesario**: las variables `a` y `b` sólo son usadas en los bucles `for`, estarían mejor declaradas en el propio bucle para limitar su ámbito.
- **Nombres de variables innecesariamente cortos**: nombrar variables como `a` y `b` proporciona muy poca información acerca de su misión o intención de uso; evita usar nombres de variables de un sólo carácter y busca nombres auto-explicativos.
- **Variables no inicializadas**: La respuesta de [Pako LordPakus](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/12926/2742) es excelente. Añadiré que en la prueba que he hecho yo, en el compilador que he probado tu codigo `fila` y `columna` se crean con el valor `2'147'483'647` (`0x7fffffff`) con lo que intenta crear un VLA de varios millones de megas lo cual desborda la pila en tiempo de ejecución. En el caso de que `fila` y `columna` obtuvieran valores menores a los capturados en `cin`, durante la escritura saldrías de la memoria del arreglo (ya que `matriz` se crea **antes** de capturar los valores de su tamaño) y podría pasar cualquier cosa: podría funcionar, no funcionar, el programa podría ser abortado en tiempo de ejecución o [demonios podrían salir disparados de tus fosas nasales](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

Comment: Chicos gracias por sus respuestas , las lei y bueno voy a tomar sus consejos y mejorar, ahora entiendo mas un poco de como trabaja las variables no inicializadas, no me tirar ningun error al compilar, si deja de funcionar en el momento de hacer pruebas. voy a modificar el codigo gracias.

Answer (score 1):

En estos casos, lo que se pude hacer es declarar un tipo de dato vector, anteponiendo la librería `#include <vector>` en los encabezados. 
De todos modos, hay un error en el orden de la sentencia. Declaras una matriz 
`int matriz [fila][columna];` antes de leer las variables fila y columna. Recordar que los programas se ejecutan **siempre** de arriba hacia abajo. y al declararlas sin antes haberlas leído va a tirar error, pues los arreglos deben tener una capacidad.
En lugar de usar una matriz en C++, puedes usar la siguiente sintaxis de vectores `vector<int> nombreMatriz(fila*columna);` El requisito de esto es que tenga declarada la librería `#include<vector>` y que la declaración del vector se haga **siempre** después de leer la capacidad del vector. Otra cosa importante es declarar las variables al principio del programa 
El programa quedaría de la siguiente manera:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

int main(){
    int a,fila,columna;
    system ("color F3");
    cout << "\t\t\t PROGRAMA DE MATRIZ EJ 1 C++" << endl << endl;
    cout << "Ingrese el valor de filas que quiere que tenga la matriz: "; cin >> fila;
    cout << "Ingrese el valor de columnas que quiere que tenga la matriz: "; cin >> columna;

    vector<int> Matriz(fila*columna);

    cout << "Ingrese el valor de los elementos de la matriz: " << endl;

    for(a = 0; a < fila*columna ; a++)
        cin >> Matriz[a];      

    cout << "Matriz introducida:\n";

    for(a = 0; a < fila*columna ; a++ )
        cout << "Fila " << "[" << a << "]" << " " << "columna " << "[" << a << "]: " << Matriz[a] << endl; 
    system ("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Esta aseveracion no es correcta "A diferencia de C, C++ no permite declarar ni un arreglo ni una matriz con una capacidad definida por el usuario"

Comment: Corregido, oración eliminada